# Convert date math expression to date Elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I'm looking for a nice way to retrieve date and time information from a date math expression passed to Elasticsearch. If I query on a time range using e.g 'now-2d/s' as gt-value, is there any way to know what date was actually used internally by Elasticsearch?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the objective content particular question; But when do people learn, how to [state a proper](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question? This includes a meaningful topic, proper text in the question itself as well as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have to show the code you've come up with in a condensed form, otherwise people cannot help you.

Comment: @JensHöpken and the code that you want me to include Jens, what do you expect it to do? Are you of the impression that it is completely impossible to post a valid question without posting this "code"? More to the point, do you grasp the question and do you thing you would have any better chance at solving it had I included this "code"? Instead of bashing down at the question without providing any useful example of where I went wrong when posting it I'm afraid I'll get very little constructive feedback from your comment, and if you ment anything else than being smug you did not succeed.

Comment: @J-Wangers Then I wish you all the best, in solving your problem.

Comment: Seriously though, could you not try to be more specific in what information you lack to be able to help me. @JensHöpken

Comment: After your rant on how this entire platform is basically bad, I can only say that you should read the above links. I can't help you with your problem at all, since I don't know Elasticsearch. All I know that I could not reproduce the problem you are having. Which is necessary for people that know Elasticsearch to help you. That's why there is a review process in place to ensure a good quality of questions and answers. And this is how I discovered this particular one.

Comment: @JensHöpken It's not a rant about how this platform is bad, it's a rant about how you're trying to shoot me down, saying that I don't know how to formulate a valid question event though you lack the subject matter knowledge to even understand my question. I'm not asking for the length of a piece of string, I'm asking pretty concretely if the possibility exists in ES to get a date from a date math expression. I agree that questions should be well put, and in my case I think it is. Not every question is well put in the format 'my code does not work, here's the code, I've tried this'.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you use the validate API.

indexname/_validate/query?rewrite=true

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "modifiedDate": {
        "gte": "now-1y/y",
        "lte": "now/y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you get:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "valid": true,
  "explanations": [
    {
      "index": "indexname",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": "+modifiedDate:[1640995200000 TO 1704067199999] #FieldExistsQuery [field=_primary_term]"
    }
  ]
}
```

This lets you see exactly what value is being used for a given query.